# Problems with Angular2 on macOS Sierra

Tags: angularjs, angular, macos-sierra

I have upgraded to mac os sierra GM version and having issue with angular2 cli.
I had it installed before the upgrade and it was running fine. I’m getting `command not found` on terminal when I try anything with `ng`.
I have tried to reinstall with command `sudo install -g angular-cli` and `sudo install angular-cli` it but nothing seems to work. I have the required nodejs and npm installed as pre-reqs for angular-cli.
Looking for some possible solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot the command name: `npm`.

Try this:

```
sudo npm install -g angular-cli
```

Also be sure you have installed Node 6.6.0 (that includes with npm 3.10.3).

Best,
Demetrio